# Do Libraries like GLUT & GLFW have the same functionality as SDL?

Tags: opengl, sdl, glfw

I was watching this video about OpenGL 3 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMgfddy7S7Q

And while talking about libraries to work with OpenGL (at 3:00) he mentions GLFW, freeGLUT and GLUT to use to create the window.

But can they handle input and sound as well like SDL?

And if so should I be using SDL? Or is GLFW more tuned for making games specifically in OpenGL?

Comment: Go look at their documentation. GLFW only handles window creation and input (no sound, image loading, etc.) Unsure about freeGLUT.

Comment: If your goal is learning, you should at least once do that all without any wrapper library, to know what this wrappers doing under the hood. After that you'll know what you need and what you don't. Recommendations of specific tool/library is quite off-topic.

Comment: I agree, the last paragraph makes this a library recommendation question, but if removed it is actually within the guidelines. That is, it asks for the differences between SDL and GLUT/GLFW. Those are objective questions.

Comment: probably the easiest way for you to answer your question is download the old SGI examples and see what the GLUT parts do: http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/glut_examples/examples/examples.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, GLUT and GLFW are frameworks that manage OpenGL context creation and windowing (***which includes input***) mostly. GLUT has a few components that are actually designed to draw things, but by in large it is there to setup GL only.

SDL, on the other hand, includes sound which neither GLFW nor GLUT do but also includes utilities to load resources such as image files. It is a much more end-to-end solution, whereas GLFW and GLUT are only designed to facilitate rendering/windowing. To do the same thing using GLFW, you would need to throw in some libraries such as SOIL (or work directly with libpng, libjpeg, etc.) and also find an audio library.

You do not need any of these things to make a game in truth. I interact directly with OpenGL (WGL/GLX/CGL) on Windows, Linux and OS X in my work but the extra time necessary to debug and maintain each of these platforms at such a direct level can be a real nuisance. If writing extra code specific to each platform you run on is unappealing then you should definitely consider GLFW, etc.